# Error with facebook connections in android

Tags: android

I have a problem with facebook. 
In connection i have:

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token="+ token);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        int sc = con.getResponseCode();
```

and I get:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "www.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname
```

I have all permissions in manifest like:access_network and Internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve my problem:

```
 HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        con.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setDoInput(true);
        // Starts the query
        con.connect();
        int sc = con.getResponseCode();
```